# Announcement: I am stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion

I do not want to give a big speech, but I am stepping down as moderator. I have not been nearly as invested in this site or its maintenance as I once was, and my activity has been dwindling. For a time, I thought I would eventually return in earnest. But my priorities and my perspectives on the direction of the site have shifted; I think it is time for me to officially step down.

To be clear, I don't have a complaint against anyone or anything. I am not taking a principled stand for or against something. It is simply my time.

I have spoken with the Community Team, and my diamond will be disappearing presently.

Thank you for your support, and good luck.

Comment: We'll miss you! Thank you for your service

Comment: Thank you for your service!

Comment: @mixedmath thanks so much for your hard work. You will be sorely missed. phil.SE can be pretty grueling.